# Joel's hard line on closing questions - which we overruled?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Thought this was worth a discussion](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/question-closed-and-its-probably-best-that-way/), and worth pointing out as it shows the mentality of stackexchange being hard on questions has been around a while, isn't just travel, and is the right way, despite how frustrating it can be ;)

> If you’ve poked around our network, then you’ve probably noticed that
>   we hate fun at Stack Exchange. Hard-line Q&A is in our evil DNA.

it goes on to describe how subjective questions get crushed if they don't 'improve the internet'.

> Too local? Take it to Yelp. Too easy? Take it to Google. Too
>   subjective? Take it to Quora. Too fun? Take it to Facebook.

Which brings ME to the following, a blog post on SO describes the very moment Joel closed a question on our site, and how we overruled it.

> Which brings me to yesterday. It was late afternoon. The sky was gray.
>   And I watched over Joel’s shoulder as he personally closed [a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/easiest-way-to-join-the-mile-high-club-mhc)
>   that was causing some buzz at the Travel site. Joel said the question
>   was crude and intentionally provocative. I suggested maybe there
>   wasn’t enough information available to make an assumption about the
>   user’s intentions. Joel said maybe, and he proceeded to close the
>   question. I swiveled back to my desk and got back to whatever it was I
>   was doing.

Thoughts? :)

Comment: Listen to [the latest Stack Exchange podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/podcast-50-listen-to-this-podcast/). They're changing a bunch of this stuff yet again, apparently including getting rid of "too localized" as a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the mufti's orders we will have to close a good deal of the questions here. However, by having this extreme view he is pulling the rug from under his own feet. Less questions are allowed, less users attracted etc. Eventually the site will dry up.

Furthermore, I do not really understand the logic of closing. If a question is better on Yelp, Google, Quora or Facebook, as he say, why should we keep it here? A closed question remains on the stack, can be up-voted, commented, etc. And if a comma is displaced the questions will reappear on the top of the pile, although it is not desirable.

The actual policy is wish-wash. We want to be better and smarter than the others and improve the internet (sic). But we end up accepting (nearly) everything nevertheless ...